# pytest testing other thread is running

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a class which has a function do some work in a new thread.

```py
class MyClass:
  def start(self):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.something, name='background_thread')
     thread.daemon = True
     thread.start()
```

I'm writing test for `start` function, and this is my code:

```py
def test_start(self, mocker):
  mocker.patch('main.MyClass.something')
  app = MyClass()
  app.start()

  threads = []
  for thread in threading.enumerate():
    threads.append(thread.name)

  assert 'background_thread' in threads
```

When I run this test, it shows that assertion failed:
[image]

But when I run it in debug mode, it shows `background_thread` in `threads` list:
[image]

Can some one explain why it happen?

I'm using

- `python`: `3.10`
- `pytest`: `7.1.2`

Comment: I suppose that patched `something` doesn't take time, so it is already done when you call `enumerate` and this thread is dead. I'd suggest to patch with `time.sleep` so that it doesn't terminate so quickly.

Comment: And `list(threading.enumerate())` would be sufficient, plus you can run `assert 'background_thread' in threading.enumerate()` directly.

Comment: @SUTerliakov add `time.sleep` worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @SUTerliakov `assert 'background_thread' in threading.enumerate()` won't work, `threading.enumerate()` returns list of `Thread` object.

Comment: Augh, sorry, my bad, should be `assert 'background_thread' in [t.name for t in threading.enumerate()]`. Simple comprehension is faster (not important in this case) and more readable in general.